# How to check an extension is namespaced?

Tags: templates, extensions, joomla-4.x, namespace

I'm working on [namespaced templates feature](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/30816) and I came to the point where I need to check if an extension is namespaced or not.

One possibility would be to load the `templateDetails.xml` file and check manually. I only wonder if there is anything in the Joomla namespace libraries that saves the day.

I also appreciate any suggestion/reply.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I could think of is just to check the XML file:

```
$templatesPath = ((int) $this->template->client_id === 1 ? JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR : JPATH_SITE) . '/templates/';
$templateDetails = $templatesPath . $this->template->name . '/templateDetails.xml';
$templateXML = simplexml_load_file($templateDetails);

if ($templateXML->namespace === null || (string) $templateXML->namespace === '') {
  // do something with non-namespaced template
}
```

Till other solution comes up, this is the only thing I got it working.

Comment: A suggestion to maintain your logic but make the code less wide and more concise: https://3v4l.org/nOMeB

Comment: thanks @mickmackusa, we already managed that, I've update my answer with latest code, check & upvote https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/30816